# Remember scrollbar position after form submit in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, laravel-blade

Is it possible to remember scrollbar position after form submit and returning back to the home page?

Here is my **form**:

```
<form method="post" action="{{Route('sites.liking')}}">
  <input name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$meme->likes}}" name="likes">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$meme->id}}" name="likeid">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" name="sendeduser">
  <button class="linking">+ {{$meme->likes}}</button>
</form>
```

**Routing**:

`Route::post('/', ['uses' => 'LikingComments@liking', 'as' => 'sites.liking']);`

**Controller function**:

```
public function liking(Request $request) {
  //Function guts
  return redirect('/')->with('status', $id);
}
```

I've tried several scripts but it always scrolls to the top of the page.

***Is there a some way to go back to the same place of the page ?***

Comment: You should GET scrollbar position as soon as user clicks submit button and save it to somewhere that wont disappear after refresh(localstorage, or smt like that), and then, in homepage, do control of it.

Comment: You could add an `id` attribute to an element (`<div id="likes">`) and use `#likes` in your URL to jump to the position of that element

Comment: Beside coding, i not recommend do something like this. If it's required by your design, you should reconsider the design. Think about all edge cases where this would snap the user even if he don't want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved up that problem by adding an id to an element, new routing and changing main function.

```
<div id="{{$meme->id}}">
 <form method="post" action="{{Route('sites.liking')}}">
  <input name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$meme->likes}}" name="likes">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$meme->id}}" name="likeid">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}" name="sendeduser">
  <button class="linking">+ {{$meme->likes}}</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Changed function:

```
public function liking(Request $request)
{
 //Function guts


 return redirect()->action('LikingComments@indexliking', ['id' => $id])->with('status', $id);
}
```

Routing:

```
Route::get('/#{id}' , ['uses' => 'LikingComments@indexliking', 'as' => 'indexliking']);
```

It don't work perfectly but it's fine for me. Thank you for your answers especially @kerbholz

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage or sessionStorage to save current scroll position (scrollTop).
and then assign it to scrollTop when you reload that previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it just like Piotr did it. A bit late but anyway, maybe it helps someone else

my return contains an identifier, in my case the component id

```
return redirect(url()->previous().'#component'.$component->id)
```

and my view creates the identifying html tags for each entry

```
<tr id="component{{ $component->id }}">
```

If it you really need to be at the exact same point you should look into saving the scroll position in local storage and retrieving it after redirecting back.